# No Event listeners for UI Bootstrap popover

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover, event-listener

I used following plunker code in my application(HTML & angularJS) for popover & it doesn't seem to work. I checked DOM & looks like Popover is not created as there are no Event Listeners

[Popover in Modal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNzvF.jpg)

```
   <button popover-trigger="focus" uib-popover-template="'yes-no.html'" popover-title="Some title here?" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
```

---

Edit: Here is the screenshot from my application which doesn't have any event Listeners & that's the reason no Popover is being displayed. Any help is highly appreciated

[image]

Here is the brief description about the architecture

I have an MVC page(that has a angularJS App & controller), within the controller i use $modal.open to open an html( i have defined the new controller within the $modal.open). Popover should be within html modal page, the problem is there are no event listeners on the button & so  popover doesn't seem to work

I checked Framework listeners & there are none. Looks like this is the problem

[image]

Comment: looking at your plunk, it seems the popover is created when the cancel button is pressed

Comment: Yes, it creates the popover when the cancel button is pressed

Comment: ok, i ran a little test, i took your code and pasted it on the modal example, it looks like the modal renders the popover properly https://plnkr.co/edit/oDEb2Pnr01PWVMo3Z26s

Comment: Okay, i was able to run successfully in my test application but when trying to integrate in existing application popover doesn't seem to work(nothing gets generated). Only difference  is popover in existing application is part of modal page where as the test application it is in a separate page. Thanks for your plunker, i will see if i can figure out anything

Comment: Also i have noticed when i changed popover-trigger to focus i am not seeing any Event Listener & probably that is the reason popover is not generating. Any idea why this is happening

Comment: I think the whole problem is i am not seeing any Event Listeners for any popover trigger & here is what i have ---popover-trigger="'click'"  & also tried with popover-trigger="'focus'"